# HTML/CSS footer on mobile site doesn't work on IPhone safari How to fix?

Tags: html, iphone, css, mobile, footer

I'm having trouble with a mobile website. The client wants these text based buttons/links on the bottom so I added them, but I'm a little rusty on using size percentages.

I need to make the look like this and stay on the same line, but stretch accordingly so the text isn't too small to read.
I can make it so it looks and works fine on a Samsung or Nexus, but using an IPhone always caused the third text element to move to the next line rather than shrink.

Mobile website: http://teetimelawn.com/m/html/index.html

**EDIT (screnshot of a iphone simulator showing my problem):**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/axoHI.png

How it typically looks on android phones liks a nexus: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A44zu.jpg

---

HTML:

```
<section id="footer">
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="full"><a href="http://www.teetimelawncare.com">Full Site</a></div>
        <div id="foot"><a href="tel:18156096969">Call Us</a></div>
        <div id="footer-right">Tee Time Lawn Care &copy; </div>  
    </div>
</section> <!-- #footer -->
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    color: #fff;    
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background:#00CC00;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
}

#foot {
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    height: 30px;
}

#full {
    font-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#footer-right {
    font-size: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of one that's working and one that isn't?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/R0RE0i5.png

I tried the suggestion below....the issue is keeping the text resizing to fit inside the box on all mobile devices and staying inline to boot. I want this site to work on tablets as well.

Comment: added a screen shot of a working one:http://i.imgur.com/tkpLv4V.jpg

That's a nexus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with the HTML. First, you have two `ids`; only one should be present. Second, the divs for full, foot, footer-right should be a list item. There really isn't a reason that they need to be `ids`. if you want to do a special color for the middle, give it a class.

```
<ul class="footer">
  <li><a href="http://www.teetimelawncare.com">Full Site</a></li>
  <li class="purple"><a href="tel:18156096969">Call Us</a></li>
  <li><span>Tee Time Lawn Care ©</span></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use text-justify to justify the lis. Take a look at this CodePen for more information on that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/djoah

Answer (score 1):

your font-size is set 100%, so it will get small when you squeeze the window. change it to 22px or something then it will remain constant.